# PHP Reference to `$this`

Tags: php

How does PHP interpret `&$this` ? Why is it allowed?

I came to this question with the following issues, which looks like a bug in PHP 7.1 and 7.2.
It occurs with `&$this` references and cross-namespace calls and `call_user_func_array`.
I think `&$this` is pretty weird and should not be allowed, but WordPress uses it for example.

Consider this code:

```
<?php
namespace N {
    function callNeedRef( $a ) {
        var_dump( $a );
        call_user_func_array( 'needRef', $a );
    }
}

namespace {
    function needRef( &$r ) { } 
    function callNeedRef( $a ) {
        var_dump( $a );
        call_user_func_array( 'needRef', $a );
    }   

    class C {
        function f() {
            $a = $this;
            callNeedRef( array( &$a ) );        // no warning (expected), OK!
            N\callNeedRef( array( &$a ) );      // no warning (expected), OK!
            callNeedRef( array( &$this ) ); // no warning (expected), but 7.1,7.2: var_dump prints no '&'           
            N\callNeedRef( array( &$this ) );   // 7.1,7.2: warn and var_dump prints no '&'         
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    echo phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
    $o = new C();
    $o->f();
}
```

And its output:

```
7.2.0RC2
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  &object(C)#1 (0) {
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  &object(C)#1 (0) {
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(C)#1 (0) {
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(C)#1 (0) {
  }
}


Warning:  Parameter 1 to needRef() expected to be a reference, value given in reftest.php on line 6
```

As already stated in the code, the two last `var_dump`s dont mark the object as reference. And the last call even produces as warning.

Comment: just as an update. Here's what happens in all php versions: https://3v4l.org/8Ftbh#output

Answer (score 0):

The val (`$this`) is not global, the scope changes, therefore it get's `ZCAL_STR_COPY`ied.

```
case EXTR_OVERWRITE:
        /* GLOBALS protection */
        if (var_exists && ZSTR_LEN(var_name) == sizeof("GLOBALS")-1 && !strcmp(ZSTR_VAL(var_name), "GLOBALS")) {
                break;
        }
        if (var_exists && ZSTR_LEN(var_name) == sizeof("this")-1  && !strcmp(ZSTR_VAL(var_name), "this")) {
                zend_class_entry *scope = zend_get_executed_scope();
                if (scope && ZSTR_LEN(scope->name) != 0) {
                        break;
                }
        }
        ZVAL_STR_COPY(&final_name, var_name);
        break;
```

Thank's for making me look into PHP Source Code for [array.c](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=ext/standard/array.c;h=70997529423f14e58bad919a2458ad99c9f118d5#l1844) :)